# How to install webmin on a desktop not on a server?

Tags: webserver, webmin

Need Help How to install webmin on ubuntu 12.04 desktop not on ubuntu server?

i wan't to install webmin on my ubuntu desktop not on server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1985535

Comment: I assume [this was the post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1985535&p=11965112#post11965112) that gave the solution. Could you please post a summary here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm now adding the steps to install `Webmin 1.580` on Ubuntu 12.04. Please ensure that you have `OpenSSL` installed, otherwise you are not going to be able to run Webmin over TLS.
To do that just run
`openssl version` in your terminal, you should get an output similar to the following, if you have it installed:
`OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012`

There is no specialized Ubuntu version, so we need to install the Debian version and make manual changes. The steps are:

- First, we need to add the official Webmin repository to our list of software packages by using the following:
  Add the following line at the end of `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:
  `deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib`
  You can use, `sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list` for the above.
- Now we need to add Webmin author Jamie Cameron’s public key to our keyring. Do this from your home directory:
  `wget http://www.webmin.com/jcameron-key.asc`
  When the `jcameron-key.asc` file has completed its download, do the following:
  `sudo apt-key add ~/jcameron-key.asc`
- Now we can install Webmin from the repo we added:

  - Update your repository index:
    `sudo apt-get update`
  - Now install webmin using:
    `sudo apt-get install webmin`

You should now be able to access `webmin` at `https://<hostname>:10000/`
as root with your root password, or as any user who can use sudo
to run commands as root.

*Courtesy:* http://www.kelvinwong.ca/2010/05/22/installing-webmin-on-ubuntu-server-10-04-lts-lucid/
*N.B:* This is a faithful reproduction of the steps posted in the above link.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark this as the answer, if everything went find for you.